# Изменить стиль блока при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не знаю JavaScript вообще. Только CSS и HTML. Помогите написать код, пожалуйста.

Допустим, у меня есть блок ***A***

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

У него есть ***стиль***

```
#a {width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute (или relative, не суть); top:0px}
```

При ***нажатии*** на этот блок нужно чтобы у него был

```
top:100px; left:50px
```

к примеру.

Насколько мне известно, средствами CSS можно лишь сделать так, чтобы на время нажатия на этот блок он перемещался, а когда отпустить кнопку мыши - он встанет на свое место. Как сделать, чтобы при клике на этот блок он переместился, а при еще одном клике встал назад?  ***Очень, очень и очень желательно без JavaScript, ибо я его пока что ВООБЩЕ не знаю, если возможно.*** Если невозможно, помогите написать скрипт-шаблон, и хотя бы отдаленно расскажите какая команда за что отвечает. Спасибо большое, надеюсь поможете))

**UPD** Возможно сделать так, чтобы при клике у него менялись свойства? Или при клике вместо id="a" у него становился id="a1" ? Это возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже тыщу раз отвечал на подобный вопрос:

HTML

```
<label class="switchable">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div id="a"></div>
</label>
```

CSS

```
#a {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.switchable input {
    display:none;
}
.switchable input:checked+#a {
    top:100px;
    left:50px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sFEH4/

фокус в использовании :checked и следующего за ним div.

ограничение способа - нельзя помещать в такой `<div>` никаких input

Comment: ...Спасибо, пригодилось...долго ищу!
 А как в таком случае сделать,чтобы по клику не один блок перемещался (менял стиль), а сразу 5-7 блоков.....при чем у каждого свой стиль...

Надеюсь на помощь ибо Чайник я еще...а код нужен:)

Comment: [во первых](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling)

во вторых, используйте `<label for>` и `switchable input:checked~.myotherblocks`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал лучше переключать классы, а не менять конкретные свойства. Например, так [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2rYF/). Я закомментировал второй вариант, который помимо того что переключает класс, меняет и id элемента.